# Difference between PageHeader in Ant-Design and Ant-Design-Pro

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

How do the parameters differ between Ant Design and Ant Design Pro?

I have code written for Pro but would like to use the `tags` parameter, which does not appear to be compatible. I am having trouble finding good documentation on Pro.

Comment: English Documentation of antd pro is poor, still to this day, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antd Pro is an actual framework/solution that is built out using Antd and some principles. It has some additional components/features, but you need to use the framework. You cannot use Antd Pro like you do Antd. Antd Pro **uses** Antd to build it out along with a few more features.

So in order to use Antd Pro you must pull down the project and use that or extract the additional components/features you want out of pro and custom fit them into your project.